# How to capture UIWebView redirecting url in iOS

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebView` in my app. It loads some html page. In that html page has a button. When user click on that it redirects to another html page.If that new page is success page I want to do something in my app. How can I identify the redirecting url within my app.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Use webview delegates like `didFinishLoad` and check the url like `webView.request.URL`. If this url matches your success url (which you should have beforehand) then you can perform your action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url in this delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`,for example

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
            navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    if ([request.URL.path isEqualToString:@"Your successurl"]) {
        //Do something
    }
}
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`UIWebView` have delegate methods to get the URL what it loads.

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Try these methods